# c++ calculating 2 points based off 2 other points

Tags: c++, math, rotation, trigonometry, 2d-vector

Ok, so I'm making this fun little game in c++, unfortunately I'm stuck on making a "radar", I'm stuck on this part

[image: Example]

(EDIT, i already have `A` & `B`, the only thing i do not have is `C` & `D`)

So what i need to do is calculate the two points (`2d vector`) of `C` & `D`, they need to be in the placement like in the lil pic i made shown above (sorry, i know it's bad).

`B` will rotate around `A` so i need to calculate the position of `C` & `D` based on the how much `B` has rotated around `A`. I am going to create a triangle (e.g. draw a line from `C` to `D`, `D` to `B` & `B` to `A`)

`A` could be thought of as the center of the bottom line of the triangle, this is like the base of everything, everything rotates around `A`, and the position of `C` & `D` need to be calculated according to how much `B` has rotated around `A`.

What would be like the best way to make a lil function for this calculation?
e.g.

```
inline float returnDPoint(float A, float B)
{
    float dPoint;
    //calculate point of D based off A & B
    return dPoint;
}


inline float returnCPoint(float A, float B)
{
    float cPoint;
    //calculate point of C based off A & B
    return cPoint;
}
```

Hopefully i have worded my question well enough, thanks for the read!

Comment: You must know the angle in order to calculate the location of `A`. Add *pi/2* to the angle to compute the location of the pointer a quarter of the circle ahead, and *3pi/4* for the other point. Trigonometry.

Comment: I already have calculated the angle of A. And thanks for the comment, I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a computation to get C:

```
auto angle = atan2(b.y-a.y,b.x-a.x) + pi/2.0;
auto radius = sqrt((b.y-a.y)*(b.y-a.y)+(b.x-a.x)*(b.x-a.x));
Point C {a.x + radius * cos(angle), a.y +radius * sin(angle)};
```

Comment: so to calculate D all i would do is pi/4.0?

Comment: subtract pi/2.0 instead of adding.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for rotations by 90°, you don't need to use expensive functions such as `atan2`, `sqrt`, etc. A simple alternative would be:

```
diffx = bx - ax;
diffy = by - ay;

cx = ax - diffy = ax - by + ay;
cy = ay + diffx = ay + bx - ax;

dx = ax + diffy = ax + by - ay;
dy = ay - diffx = ay - bx + ax;
```

Comment: It will probably be. However, it is on a very low scale. So if you call it only once per frame, it will not make a difference.